# running application from visual studio in vista in port 80 gives error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

I am running an web application with Visual studio 2008 with administrator mode in Vista. It runs fine when the port is set to other than 80. But it gives an error like WebDev.Webserver.exe has stopped working. I have turned of IIS default website so no other application should be using 80 port. 
What can be the reason and how to find out if any other application is running at port 80 gives this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Skype running? Try turning it off and seeing if that helps - it's oftentimes the problem as it uses port 80. You can turn this behavior off by going to Tools->Options->Advanced->Connection and seeing if the use port 80 box is checked (and unchecking it).

You can use

```
netstat -a
```

to view the ports in use.

For a slightly different, low level approach to this analysis, you can telnet to port 80 and see if it responds with something or fails

```
telnet localhost 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TcpView](http://live.sysinternals.com/Tcpview.exe) to find out if anything else is holding the port.

Alternatively have you tried other low ports to check it's not a permissions issue?